# Environment variable check with default value in csharp

Tags: c#

Looking for more simple one liner for environment variable check with default value in csharp, any help is appreciated.

```
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable1(string envName, string defaultValue)
{
   var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envName);
   return string.IsNullOrEmpty(env) ? defaultValue : env;
}
```

Tried this code, but getting compiler error that possible null reference could be returned

```
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable2(string envName, string defaultValue)
{
  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envName)) ? defaultValue : Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `??`. [Null-coalescing operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

Null check only

```cs
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name, string defaultValue)
    => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name) ?? defaultValue;
```

Null and empty string check

```cs
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name, string defaultValue)
    => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name) is string v && v.Length > 0 ? v : defaultValue;
```

[Pattern matching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching).